# Python: detect redefinition?

Tags: python, reflection

I'm looking for a way to somehow detect if a python function or class is being redefined or even only if it is defined twice and one definition erases the other.
Can this be done with reflection somehow?
Maybe by the function (or class) itself somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Redefinition of a class does nothing to the original class, it just assigns a whole new class to the same name. Checking is easy – just save the original, and see if the name still refers to it.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    x = 1

# Save the original
_my_saved_class = SomeClass

class SomeClass(object):
    x = 2

# Check if they're the same!
if SomeClass is not _my_saved_class:
    print "SomeClass was redefined!"
```

Comment: Is there any way to check at the time when SomeClass is used without having to change the code where it's used? Or any way to be informed when the variable is overwritten?

Comment: Not really, unless you execute the code with `globals` that would track this.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve? Why do you want to know if a function is redefined?

Comment: In short I'm encrypting python files and don't want it to be possible to override functions to include print statements to reveal contents of the files. But I have another approach, I'm mainly interested.

Comment: Oh. In that case detecting/preventing redefinition won't really save you – you can for example change what a function does by replacing its `__code__`.